# What exactly is the difference between the Theorem of total probability and Baye's theorem?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The theory of total probability for dependent events states that
$ P(A) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^nP(A|E_i)P(E_i)$ and $P(A|E_i) = \frac{P(A \cap E_i)}{P(E_i)}$

which in my eyes is the same as saying $ P(E_i|A)= \frac{P(E_i)P(A|E_i)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nP(E_i)p(A|E_i)}$

mathematically they may not look the same, bt aren't they describing the same thing? Why are they different?

Comment: I know that $P(A)$ doesn't explicitly mean conditional probability, but at times, I think it does

Comment: oh, my bad.....

Comment: $P(A)$ is the probability that $A$ occurs. There's no condition implied.

Comment: That's the total probability unless I'm mistaken $P(A|E_i)$ implies conditional probability, does it not?

Comment: Not following.  You said that you thought $P(A)$ denoted a conditional probability.  It doesn't.

Comment: it denotes the total probability, right?

Comment: Not sure what your question is here.  One way to think of the law of total probability is just as $P(A)=\sum_i P(A\cap B_i)$ where the $B_i$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.  Of course you can rewrite that as a statement about conditional probability, using the definition of  conditional probability.   Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that A is a conditional event , whose totally probability depends on multiple events

Comment: This is all very unclear.  In a general probabilistic setting, one can imagine having many possible events.  Of course, some of these depend on others.  Some might be independent.  Some might be mutually exclusive, and so on.  That's just the way events are.  $P(A)$ is the probability that the event $A$ occurs, as a matter of definition.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose events $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ partition the sample space; then the law of total probability (in one form) states $$\Pr[A] = \sum_i \Pr[A \mid E_i]\Pr[E_i]. \tag{1}$$

The definition of conditional probability is $$\Pr[A \mid E_i] = \frac{\Pr[A \cap E_i]}{\Pr[E_i]}, \tag{2}$$ whenever $\Pr[E_i] > 0$.

Bayes' rule/theorem is simply the application of the above definition $(2)$, twice:

$$\Pr[E_i \mid A]\Pr[A] = \Pr[A \cap E_i] = \Pr[A \mid E_i]\Pr[E_i],$$ therefore

$$\Pr[E_i \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[A \mid E_i]\Pr[E_i]}{\Pr[A]}, \tag{3}$$

whenever $\Pr[A] > 0$.

When applying Equation $(3)$, we commonly use $(1)$ to evaluate the denominator of the right-hand side, but they are distinct theorems.